# Setting the origin point back to Center repositions my rig (and messes up my animations)

Tags: animation, origin

When I try to reset the origin point back to center, I notice my rig repositions itself detaching itself from the bone structure I built, does anyone have any idea how I can reposition the origin point without messing with the rig?

Here's how it looks before/after

[image]

After
[image]

Does anyone know what is causing my rig to detached when resetting the origin point?

Thank you for any help/info provided!

Comment: Why do you want to reset the origin point back to the center? It's normal that the model falls apart when you change the origin of a rigged mesh because then the offset distance is different. If you want to reset the origin, you need to clear the parent first with *Alt+P > Clear and Keep Transformation* (=remove the armature), then reset the origin and parent the mesh objects to the armature again (*Ctrl+P*)

Comment: Oh wait, the armature should be in the *Rest Position* before you clear the parent of the mesh objects.